# How to talk about ongoing nervous behaviours with boss without being offensive?

Tags: work-environment, coworkers, anxiety

I am working an office job under a manager who I like and trust. He's very competent, a good person, a hard worker and generally open to feedback. This is his first leadership role (about 2 years in now). I consider myself lucky to have a boss like him. We have a good work relationship and personally get along fine.

However, he has a lot of what I would describe as "nervous tendencies":

- Continuously shaking legs (and upper body)
- Continuously pacing 1 to 2 meters back and forth during stand-up meetings
- Finger-pointing at people
- Finger-snapping at people to get their attention
- Speaking way too loud in many situations
- Stuttering/Stammering, "tumbling" over own words, frequent and long pauses with "eeeehhm", extremely nasal speaking under any amount of stress
- Interrupting conversations of others

I fully trust that he is not careless or purposefully disrespectful toward anybody. However, since my desk is right next to his for about 4 months now, his constant (I mean, 100% of the time) leg/body shaking is becoming more and more irritating, to a point where I avoid my desk for hours at a time, working from somewhere else, so that I may focus on my work. This needs to change.

Also, one on one conversations with him tend to exhaust me within 5 minutes or less, because he sits back in his chair, with both legs shaking, upper body shaking and there is not a single sentence without "tumbling" over words or expressions such as "wait, let me rephrase".

I feel generally comfortable talking with people about similar irritations. A few months ago I asked him respectfully not to point and snap fingers at me, which he since only did once or twice. He immediately apologised for it and I always thanked him for being self-aware. All in all, I believe that this was a good development for both of us.

I am genuinely not sure if he is aware regarding his other behaviours. I am now looking to speak with him again, maybe this time in a more general way, however with him I feel like I would like to be extra respectful. I'm afraid addressing  *only specific behaviours* (e.g. continuous leg shaking) can come across as nagging ("There's always something") and won't be seen as respectful.

**How to talk about ongoing nervous behaviours with boss without being offensive?**

Comment: This question https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/5900/how-do-i-politely-tell-a-stranger-to-stop-making-annoying-noises-i-cant-name/10461?r=SearchResults#10461 has some good answers on addressing “unconscious” behaviour, which most of this sounds like. It is known that stress can aggravate these kind of tics.

Comment: Hey Curious! I've given your question a pretty big edit for two reasons: Questions asking 'what should I do' are off-topic, so asking us for the better of two choices isn't really a great question. I've rephrased that to leave the worry you had with one of the approaches you thought about.

Comment: The second reason for editing out all the stuff about anxiety/stress/working hours is that [we're not fond of armchair diagnoses](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1935/1599). Unless your boss has an anxiety order diagnosed by a professional, we better just focus on the behaviour he's exhibiting and avoid labels like anxiety, stressed, overworked, etcetera. You did a great job of [describing the problematic behaviours](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1389/1599), try to avoid putting labels on them and you'll get better answers that aren't distracted by those.

Answer (score 1):

I have had colleagues with (partially) similar behavior. The "help" they received from the rest of us was feedback. Sometimes it was public, as in:

> Please stop moving so much, I cannot listen to you because I watch your movement.

(provided maybe with some smiling, so the colleague would understand it is not an attack)

Other times, it was as a 1-to-1 feedback. Somebody took the colleague for a private chat, and told them what the team noticed.

---

The behavior presented by your boss is studies and taught under the discipline of "Presentation skills". You might want to have a chat with this guy in private (you say that he is quite a great person, so he would not mind getting some feedback) and tell him what you told us.

Do not forget to add some statement about "presentation skills". I will not provide provide a list of DO's and DONT's here, as the list is quite long, and some of them require extensive explanations.

A proper training will present the common (and not so common) mistakes, and ways to get rid of them (or at least to keep them under control).